# How to plot boxplot or violin plot with Seaborn using a multi-dimensional numpy array as input?

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

I've got a 2D numpy array with dimensions (500, 10) that I'd like to plot as a Seaborn violinplot or boxplot where there is a box for each of the 10 columns. What is the cleanest way to pass this to Seaborn without doing a bunch of tedious manipulation to get it into a Pandas Dataframe first? I'm confident that I can do the transformation, but I'm afraid I'm likely not understanding the best and most concise way to do so.

For example, I could do something thing like

```
all_arrays = []
cols = the_array.shape[1]
for col in range(0, cols):
     all_arrays.append(the_array[:, col])
sns.boxplot(data=all_arrays)
```

But is there a better way to split the original array into a list of arrays, or perhaps there's a better way to pass this into seaborn? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct, `boxplot()` expects a list of vectors, so you have to somehow transform your matrix into that.

You can simplify the way you write your code however: `sns.boxplot(data=[d for d in the_array.T])`

full code:

```
# create a dummy matrix 500x10
the_array = np.zeros(shape=(500,10))
for i in range(10):
    the_array[:,i] = np.random.normal(loc=i, size=(500,))

sns.boxplot(data=[d for d in the_array.T])
```

[image]